# How to create a search bar in android with a suggestion drop down appearing upon typing text in search bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a search bar with a drop down suggestion list, which appears upon typing text in the search bar. The suggestion list should completely or partially cover the activity screen(The drop down is not a new activity itself). The result should be populated from the backend, which contains a list of hard coded strings. I cannot find a solution for such a problem. Can someone please help me out here?

My MainActivity looks like this:-

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewBuilding);
    ArrayList<String> arrayBuilding = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayBuilding.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_buildings)));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayBuilding);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewBuilding);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

   }

   }
```

Comment: Something like this?  https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

Comment: Yes, something like this. But can you please explain how i can write code to display suggestions from back end? (no databases used. It is a set of hard coded strings)

Comment: see `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter`